# Contentflow - how to increase space for caption text?

Tags: contentflow

Help!

I need to increase the amount of vertical real estate space allocated for caption, in order to display 6 lines of caption text. Right now, the default is 3 lines, and if I have more than 3, the text "clashes into and overlays" the image slider bar.

Appreciate any and all help how I would do this in the contentflow.js code?
Code is found here: http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/contentflow.js

Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height in the contentFlow.css file

```
.ContentFlow .globalCaption {
text-align: center;
font-weight: 700;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 14px;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin: 2em auto;
}
```